# Don't Render Section in the Layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I use ASP.NET MVC 5 and Empty Project.

I have a Layout and a View. In the Layout I have a `RenderSection()` and before Rendered check that . And in the View I Add that section but Don't Render Section .

I getting This Error:

> The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered
>   for the layout page "~/Views/_Layout.cshtml": "Menu".

**My Layout is:**

```
<body>
<div id="menu">
    @if(IsSectionDefined("Menu"))
    {
        RenderSection("Menu", required: false);
    }
    else
    {
        <span>this is the default</span>
    }
</div>
<div id="content">
    @RenderBody()
</div>
```

and my view is :

```
 @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/_Layout.cshtml";
}

    <h2>Index</h2>
    @section Menu{
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
            <li>Item 4</li>
        </ul>
    }
```

why does not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@` symbol is also required for `RenderSection`

```
@if(IsSectionDefined("Menu"))
{
  @RenderSection("Menu", required: false);
}
else
{
  <span>this is the default</span>
}
```